# mouseover работает не так как нужно

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate

Добрый день,помогите разобраться в проблеме:
при наведение на 1 ячейку выезжает меню

```
    $('#first_td').mouseover(function(){
    $("#dop_menu").css('display','block');
    $("#dop_menu").animate({height:190}, 100);
});
```

затем я пишу,mouseout,подразумевая,что когда  ***#dop_menu***  теряем курсор это меню убирается

```
$('#dop_menu').mouseout(function(){
  $("#dop_menu").animate({height:1}, 100);
});
```

Но как только курсор попадает на меню,оно убирается,в чем проблема?Заранее спасибо!
Вот весь код http://jsfiddle.net/oLd88z1b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте событие `mouseleave`:

```
$('#first_td').mouseover(function(){
    $("#dop_menu").css('display','block');
    $("#dop_menu").animate({height:190}, 100);
});

$('#dop_menu').mouseleave(function(){
    $("#dop_menu").animate({height:1}, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо использовать `mouseenter` и `mouseleave`.

[Наглядно посмотреть разницу между всеми четырьмя событиями](http://jsfiddle.net/u9bybk0n/)